# Duplicate Array item x number of times based off a value inside each array item

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am using javascript and trying to duplicate an array item based off of the number of matches that are inside each item. I believe I need to use arr.map() to accomplish this but am having trouble with the evaluation logic.

So in the example below Item 1 would be duplicated 3 times and Item 2 would be duplicated 1 time. Thanks your help and your time.

My current array looks like:

```
"cards" = [
    {
        "text": "Item 1"
        "matches": 3
    }
    {
        "text": "Item 2"
        "matches": 1
    }
]
```

New Array would look like:

```
"newCards" = [
    {
        "text": "Item 1"
        "matches": 3
    }
    {
        "text": "Item 1"
        "matches": 3
    },
    {
        "text": "Item 1"
        "matches": 3
    },
    {
        "text": "Item 2"
        "matches": 1
    },
    {
        "text": "Item 2"
        "matches": 1
    }
]
```

attempting to use map function

```
let cardCounter = 0

let cardMap = cards.map(function (item){
cardCounter++
if (cardCounter < item.matches) {
 // Not really sure what to return here....
 // tried to return
 // return[item, item]
 // this returns an array where the first two keys are arrays and the rest undefined.
}

})
```

Comment: I don't think `map` is the right tool for the job, unless you intend to return arrays and then flatten the result.

Comment: Either `.forEach()` or `.reduce()` would be more appropriate than `.map()`

Comment: Should the duplicates be copies of the object or multiple references to the same object?

Comment: Thanks for you suggestions @barmar they would be exact duplicates of each object

Comment: That doesn't really answer my question. References to the same object are exact duplicates. Do you need to be able to modify one of them without affecting the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think `map` is a good choice as it does one value to one value mapping. If you have lodash available you could use `flatMap` in which case your `return[item, item]` idea would work. If not then perhaps use `reduce`. Something like:

```
let cardMap = cards.reduce(function (acc, item){
      for (let i = 0; i < item.matches; i++) {
             acc.push(item);
      }
      return acc;
}, []);
```

Comment: What is `item.test`, is that a typo for `item.text`? The example in the question shows that the result should contain objects, not just one property.

Comment: Thank you this worked. As I ended up pushing the entire object back into the array instead of just the text but all in all it worked. acc.push(item) thanks for your expertise

Comment: Thanks @Barmar, I've cleaned it up

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
var cards = [
    {
        "text": "Item 1",
        "matches": 3
    },
    {
        "text": "Item 2",
        "matches": 1
    }
]

var newCardsArray = [];

cards.forEach(function(element) {
    for(i = 0; i < element.matches; i++) {
        newCardsArray.push(element);
    }
});

console.log(newCardsArray);
```